# Text replace without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to change the text without reloading the page.

```
let text = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML; 
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = text.replaceAll("View more", "Read more");
```

This code works. The problem is that when there is pagination (..../shop/?page=1) on the page, it doesn't show the text change. Only when I refresh the page does the change occur. What to add to the code to make the text change happen without reloading the page?

I tried using

```
window.location.reload();
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: You have to call those two lines of code whenever the text changes. Likely the pagination doesn't trigger a reload, so hook into whatever event is thrown when pagination occurs and run the code again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want it to update the URL.

What I meant was that if there is in the URL a `/?page=1` it does not change the text

Example of:

`test.com/shop` - change the text "View more" to "Read more", no need to refresh

`test.com/product` - change the text "View more" to "Read more", no need to refresh

`test.com/shop/?page=1` - no text change "View more" to "Read more", works after refresh

`test.com/shop/?filters=cars` - no text change "View more" to "Read more", works after refresh